# mysql string searching algorithm query help

Tags: php, string, search, mysql

i have a string table in my mysql/php table.

```
 id | str  

 3  |  2,4,5,6
 4  |  7,8,9,14
 5  |  3,1,16
```

if i search with **LIKE** keyword for example "1" the result is below and its wrong

```
 id | str  

 4  |  7,8,9,14
 5  |  3,1,16
```

But the expected result is

```
 id | str  
 5  |  3,1,16
```

since "1" is only in the above row but unfortunately no idea,

help me with this,

Nithish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you're looking for is [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function

```
  select find_in_set('1', '3,2,1');  => 3
  select find_in_set('1', '3,2,14'); => 0
```

better yet, consider [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database

Comment: thats great geek frog you are thnxs :)

Comment: The final query 
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '1', string) >0

Answer (score 1):

use REGEXP instead of LIKE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

str REGEXP '1[,$]'

Comment: thnxs i cant vote up right now will do when i reach 15 of my score :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use REGEXP instead of LIKE
select * from mytable WHERE str REGEXP '(^|,)1(,|$)'
^ stands for "beginning of the string" and $ for "end of the string"
see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html for more details

Comment: thnxs i cant vote up right now will do when i reach 15 of my score :)